# Problems with asp:Button OnClick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

Here is my button

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Click Me" OnClick="doSomething(10)" runat="server" />
```

Here is the server function

```
public void doSomething(int num)
{
    int someOtherNum = 10 + num;
}
```

When I try to compile the code I get the error "Method Name Expected" for the line:

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Click Me" OnClick="doSomething(10)" runat="server" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I not allowed to pass values to the server from an OnClick event?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, the onclick event has a specific signature. It is

```
MethodName(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Second, in the markup, you need to pass the Method name only with no parentheses or params.

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Click Me" OnClick="doSomething" runat="server" />
```

Then change your codebehind as follows:

```
public void doSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....
}
```

The passing of parameters can done on a client side click event handler, in this case OnClientClick, but not on the server side handler.

Comment: So there's absolutely no way to pass that method a number as long as it's a server side method?

Comment: That's correct. You can however, read values from other input fields like textboxes or even hidden controls from inside your event handler and use that for your input calculations.

Answer (score 2):

OnClick of the Button is an Event Handler. To hook a function to an eventHandler you need to obey the Contract that was defined by the EventHandler, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005499/problems-with-aspbutton-onclick-event/1005514#1005514) by Jose. OnClick is bound to a function of the format `void doSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)`. So your function should be of the same format.

I am unsure why would want to pass a parameter to the Event Handler. If you want to take some manuplation you need to do that using some other control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" /><asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Click Me" OnClick="doSomething" runat="server" />
```

And in the Code

```
public void doSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int AnotherNumber=   Int32.Parse(txtNumber.Text)+10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is simpler solution. You could use ASP button OnCommand event. 
More about here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.oncommand.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You Must Change your Method's Structure to be like

```
public void doSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ....
    }
```

and for passing parameters you need a work around like this :

for example if you in an Html control you may but your parameter in an attribute value (such as ID in this exapmle) and then retrieve it in the server side handler

i.e to make an control changing the style color

Html :

```
<a href="" id="Grey" runat="server" onserverclick='ApplyStyleEvent'></a>
```

Code :

```
protected void ApplyStyleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Profile["SelectedStyle"] = ((HtmlControl)sender).ID;
    Response.Redirect("");
}
```

and so on.