# Button within templated control: Event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have a templated control, and I'm having problems with firing events from within it.

My actual control has more templates and is a bit more complex, but its essence is as simple as this:

```
<MyControl>
    <SomeTemplate>
        <%# Container.Blabla %>
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="someButton" OnClick="ClickAction" />
    </SomeTemplate>
</MyControl>
```

Everything seems to render fine, but hitting the button within it won't fire the event handler (which resides in my *page* codebehind). I've tested a button just outside my control (or within Repeaters), which works just fine.

I guess this boils down to the order in which everything is added or databound, but I cannot really see what. This is the essence of my control:

```
public class SomeControl : Control, INamingContainer
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(SomeTemplateContainer))]
    public ITemplate SomeTemplate { get; set; }

    public override ControlCollection Controls
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return base.Controls;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        if (ChildControlsCreated)
            return;
        base.Controls.Clear();

        // Creating template containers, instantiating in controls and adding controls
        DataBind(); 
        ChildControlsCreated = true;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        // A bunch of stuff I know work since it operates independently of my button
    }

    // Some private utility methods        
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Is ClickAction defined in your control class?  Also, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005499/problems-with-aspbutton-onclick-event

Answer (score 0):

You must Add `someButton.Click` in your `ItemCreated` event of repeater

```
var button = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("someButton") ;
button.Click += ......
```

Comment: It's not a repeater, and I did not have to do this when i tried inside a repeater. The OnClick="" markup was enough. Plus, I tried this. The event was hooked up correctly, but still never fired.